# Generate a period timestamps in a Dataframe with multiple columns and fill missing values using forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns and it looks like this:

```
date       col1 col2  col3  
2023-01-01  Y   N     NaN           
2023-01-02  Y   N     Y
```

Knowing the start and the end timestamp of df['date'], I want to generate the in between timestamps with the desired frequency. That I can do it using the code below:

`new_date = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq= '15min'))`

However, I would like to generate for the rest of the columns an equal number of rows with `len(new_date)` and fill the in between values with the value before. I know I can do that using `.ffill()` but I don't know how to generate the missing rows. The end result should look like this:

```
date                col1 col2  col3 
2020-11-01 00:00:00 Y    N     NaN
2020-11-01 00:15:00 Y    N     NaN
2020-11-01 00:30:00 Y    N     NaN
    ...         
2023-01-02 00:00:00 Y    N     Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reindex with those datetimes and forward fill the missings. This way, if the starting value was NaN, the followings will stay as NaN as well:

```py
>>> df.reindex(new_date, method="ffill")

                    col1 col2 col3
2023-01-01 00:00:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 00:15:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 00:30:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 00:45:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 01:00:00    Y    N  NaN
...                  ...  ...  ...
2023-01-01 23:00:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 23:15:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 23:30:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-01 23:45:00    Y    N  NaN
2023-01-02 00:00:00    Y    N    Y

[97 rows x 3 columns]
```

where `new_date` is `pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="15min")`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to put the .ffill out of reindex in order for it to work `df.reindex(new_date).ffill()`. Otherwise, I was getting the following error: `ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing`. Could you explain why, as the date was sorted.

Comment: np. i think some of the index was of type string, and some are datetime; what does `df.index.dtype` tell? object?

Comment: The index of the original df is: `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Comment: interesting... what does `df.index.to_series().diff().value_counts()` tell? and `pd.__version__` if possible. First one will look at the consecutive differences' frequency

Comment: `1 days       816
2 days         2
-143 days      1
144 days       1
Name: date, dtype: int64`.
The length of my df is 821, and the pd version is `1.2.1`.

Comment: thanks. so as we see, there's 1 gap where the date went 143 days towards past and otherwise it was increasing, hence the issue... Although, if you really only care about the very first and very last rows' values, you can do `df.iloc[[0, -1]].reindex(new_date, method="ffill")` and it shouldn't error.